# new to python (as in 1 week in) and need help getting pointed in the right direction

Tags: python

Need to write a code for a school lab.
Input is `First name Middle name Last Name`

Output needs to be `Last name, First initial. Middle Initial`.

It must also work with just first and last name.

Examples:

Input: `Jane Ann Doe`
Output: `Doe, J. A.`

Input: `Jane Doe`
Output: `Doe, J.`

Code thus far is:

```
# 2.12 Lab, input First name Middle name last name
# result to print Last name, fist initial. Middle initial period.
# result must account for user not having middle name

name = input()

tokens = name.split()
```

I do not understand how to write an if statement followed by print statement to get the desired output.

Comment: - [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166)
- [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822) - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Vic, your specification and sample output did not agree for the three-word one. `"Jane Ann Doe"` should have become `"Doe, J. A."` rather than `"Doe, J. D."`. Please check to make sure my edits correctly reflect your intent.

Answer (score 0):

With what you have so far, `tokens` will be a list of the words you entered, such as `['Jane', 'Ann', 'Doe']`.

What you need to do is to print out the last of those items in full, followed by a comma. Then each of the other items in order but with just the first letter followed by a period.

You can get the last item of a list `x` with `x[-1]`. You can get each of the others with a loop like:

```py
for item in x[:-1]:
    doSomethingWith(item)
```

And the first character of the string item can be extracted with `item[0]`.

That should hopefully be enough to get you on your way.

---

If it's *not* enough, read on, though it would be far better for you if tou tried to nut it out yourself first.

...

No? Okay then, here we go ...

---

The following code shows one way you can do this, with hopefully enough comments that you will understand:

```py
import sys

# Get line and turn into list of words.

inputLine = input("Please enter your full name: ")
tokens = inputLine.split()
print(tokens)

# Pre-check to make sure at least two words were entered.

if len(tokens) < 2:
    print("ERROR: Need at least two tokens in the name.")
    sys.exit(0)

# Print last word followed by comma, no newline (using f-strings).

print(f"{tokens[-1]},", end="")

# Process all but the last word.

for namePart in tokens[:-1]:
    # Print first character of word followed by period, no newline.

    print(f" {namePart[0]}.", end="")

# Make sure line is terminated by a newline character.

print()
```

You could no doubt make that more robust against weird edge cases like a first name of `"."` but it should be okay for an educational assignment.

But it handles even more complex names such as `"River Rocket Blue Dallas Oliver"` (yes, I'm serious, that's a real name).

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it did not help me.  I'm trying to see if I can find an example so I can work my way into piecing it together.

Comment: @Vic, I gave you the necessary information in the first part of the answer which should allow you to piece something together. I also gave you a very-well-commented complete example should you have trouble with the first part. Not sure what else I can do to make it easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
tokens = name.split()
if int(len(tokens)) > 2:
    print(tokens[-1] + ",", tokens[0][0]+".", tokens[1][0]+".")
else:
    print(tokens[-1] + ",", tokens[0][0]+".")
```

Comment: I think that third argument to the first print should be `tokens[1][0]`, yes? As it stands, that gives you the first letter of the *last* name. Actually, I've just noticed the question sample output is most likely wrong, and disagrees with the spec which is probably why you did it that way. Have "fixed" the question (and this answer).

Comment: Yes, I didn't understand what was meant so I followed the output examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
a=input()
name=a.split(" ")
index=len(name)

if index==3:
    print(f"{name[-1]},{name[-3][0]}.{name[-2][0]}.")
else:
    print(f"{name[-1]},{name[-2][0]}.")
```

Here is the explanation of the code:

First,using `input()`,we get the name of the person.

Then,we split the name using `.split()`with the parameter (written in the parenthesis) as `" "`
next we will find the no.of elements in the list (.split() returns a list) for the if statement

Then we print the output through the if statement shown above and using indexing ,we extract the first letter.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, I was able to piece together a code using bits from your explanation.  It is not pretty but works.  Will be trying to clean it up later.

Answer (score 0):

```
# 2.12 Lab, input First name Middle name last name
# result to print Last name, fist initial. Middle initial period.
# result must account for user not having middle name

name = input()

tokens = name.split()

if len(tokens) == 2:  # to identify if only two names entered
last_name = tokens[1]
first_init = tokens[0][0]
    print(last_name, ',', first_init,'.',sep='')

if len(tokens) == 3:   # to identify if three names entered
last_name = tokens[2]
first_init = tokens[0][0]
middle_init = tokens [1][0]
    print(last_name, ',',' ',first_init,'.', ' ', middle_init,'.',sep='')
```